# What extensions are used in a module, and what do they mean?

Tags: files

I suppose there's a drupal page somewhere that explains this, but I can't find it.

When creating a module, you can have files that end with .module, .info, .inc, etc...

What are all the file extensions that are recognized and what do they do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extensions that are specific for Drupal, or that have a specific meaning in Drupal, are the following ones:

- The **.api.php** extension is used for the file describing the hooks used by a module, such as [system.api.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/7).
- The **.install** extension is used for the file that is used when a module is installed, such as [system.install](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.install/7). It is also loaded when Drupal is verifying the requirements needed from a module.
- The **.inc** extension is used for any secondary file that contains code that is loaded only when necessary. If the code is used in specific cases, such as when a specific menu callback is being invoked, then the code is moved in a separated .inc file. Often, you will find modules using a file with the **.admin.inc** extension (e.g. [node.admin.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.admin.inc/7)) that includes all the code necessary to run the administrative interface, and a file with **.pages.inc** extension (e.g. [node.pages.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/7)) that contains the code executed for other menu callbacks. If a module implements tokens, in Drupal 7 you will find files using **.tokens.inc** as extension (e.g. [user.token.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.tokens.inc/7)); those are the files where the implementations of [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7), and [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) are looked for (see [system_hook_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_hook_info/7)).
- The **.info** extension is used for the file describing the module, or the theme, such as [system.info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.info/7). It contains metadata, such as the required Drupal version, the minimum PHP version with which the module/theme is compatible, and other information specific for the module, or the theme.
- The **.module** extension is used for the main file of a module, such as [system.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/7).
- The **.test** extension is used for the files containing the testing code (e.g. [system.test](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.test/7)), which is actually running on the SimpleTest framework.
- The **.theme** extension was used from themes not using PHPTemplate template engine. In Drupal 6 (and before) the extension was used from the [chameleon.theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!chameleon!chameleon.theme/6) file; in Drupal 7, there aren't themes using that extension.
- The **.tpl.php** extension is used for the template files used from theme functions, such as [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7).

Third-party modules can use specific extensions, such as the following ones:

- The .views_default.inc extension is used for files (e.g. [node.views_default.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node.views_default.inc/7)) containing the code to implement the default views used from a module that integrates with the Views module.
- The **.views_template.inc** extension is used for files (e.g. [node.views_template.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node.views_template.inc/7)) containing the code for views templates.
- The **.rules.inc** extension is used for files containing code for integrating with the Rule module.

Answer (score 5):

A quick googling of 'writing drupal modules' returned the following developer guides:

- [Creating Drupal 6.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/231276)
- [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112)

There is also a project, [Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples), which gives lots of insight into module writing and best practices, etc. It has versions for multiple releases of Drupal as well.

With more respect to .inc files, the documentation for [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/6) explains how Drupal includes them within modules. Basically they are the Drupal's way of breaking up modules into more manageable pieces. Otherwise, a complex module might have a gigantic .module file.

Also, sometimes modules don't need all of their code loaded; so, code that is only called in certain routines is delegated to a .inc file for performance reasons and loaded only when needed.

If screencasts are more helpful, you might want to check out [Your First Module - A Mostly Painless Intro to Drupal Development](http://2011.drupalcampla.com/sessions/your-first-module-mostly-painless-intro-drupal-development) and click on the screencast link.

Bob over at http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast has some great podcasts as well; most of his are D6, but he is getting more and more into D7.

Comment: I don't really see a breakdown on either of those pages. Like where does it talk about .inc files?

Comment: `.inc` files are php include files, and are not specific to drupal, but to any php environment.  a quick grep through any of the .module files will show you what's going on, as will the opening `<?php` tag.  But these links will show you all the drupal specific files like .module, .info, .install, etc.

Comment: You should really summarize this as just providing links aren't considered good answers on DA or any other SE sites.

Comment: @kylex I think yo are here for some a,b,c ... Tutorial !

Comment: The question is about the extensions normally used in Drupal; the first link is for a page describing how to write a Drupal module, but it doesn't report the extensions normally used from Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

A module conatins mainly 3 imp files

1. List item- .info file -> a file which contains d module information like name version etc.
2. List item- .module file -> a file that describes how a module works.
3. List item- .install file -> this file is run for first time when the module is configured.this is maily to create database tables and the corresponding fields,this file has to be updated if we make any version change in module.